# Overlaying leftside vertical nav with top nav in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build admin UI using bootstrap 4 where I'm having two menus. One vertical and other at top bar. I want to have navigation to be something like this:

[image]

While doing so I tried something like this in my html code:

```
<div class="dashboard">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-white">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Test 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Test 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Test 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="nits-nav-left-aside bg-white">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm px-0 flex-row flex-nowrap">
            <ul class="nav flex-sm-column flex-row">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Side 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Side 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Side 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownSideMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Side
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownSideMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in CSS part I'm using something like this:

```
.dashboard {
    color: #0a0302;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #EAEDED;
 }

 nav {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 }

 .nits-nav-left-aside {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
  }

 .nits-nav-left-aside > nav > ul {
    top: 100px;
  }
```

But somehow my UI looks something like this:

[image]

For your reference this is the link to view layout: http://demo.nitseditor.com/html#/dashboard

Help me out with these.

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about what you want to change about the results you're getting? (The results I get when viewing a page with only the code you've provided don't look like your results screenshot, so I can't reproduce the issue. There's likely some other CSS at play in what you've rendered up there.)

Comment: @Kerri Please find the link http://demo.nitseditor.com/html#/dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have given a fixed height of **70px** to **nav** which is creating a problem try giving height to individual class instead of **nav**

Answer (score 0):

Check out my website: [webawesome.000webhostapp.com](https://webawesome.000webhostapp.com)

Then go to inspect>sources>webawesome
Look at my CSS, JavaScript, and HTML.

Comment: You have only one top bar menu, I have two one vertical and other on horizontal top bar position, I hope you are getting my desired output as asked in my question.